# Passing a boolean value from UI to rest controller

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have an application with front end on Angular and backend using Spring/Java.

The functionality is like show employee details and there is a checkbox in the UI. Following should be the behavior

1. when checkbox is checked, show all employees for a given department
2. when the checkbox is unchcecked, exclude some employees based on some criteria (this logic is done on backend)

For this, I have a get request and I added an additional parameter of type boolean to the "get" request.

This is how the code is for the UI component

```
 get(include:boolean, dept:string):Observable<EmployeeList>{
   let params = new HttpParams();
   params=params.set('dept',dept);
   params=params.set('include',String(include)); 
}
```

Please note that I am using casting to String for include param since I am not finding a way to pass the boolean value from UI using HttpParams.

On the backend the controller is like this

```
@GetMapping(value="/employee")
public EmployeeList list(@RequestParam String dept, String include) {
   boolean flag = Boolean.parseBoolean(include);
   .............
}
```

So I am trying to avoid the following

```
1. params=params.set('include',String(include)); 
2. boolean flag = Boolean.parseBoolean(include);
```

Is there a way? For post and put request,we use form which works fine with booleans.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to avoid this cast, unfortunately.  Since this is an HTTP GET request, this is passed via a query string, which has to be a string according to the http standard.  There might be a way to tell Java to do it automatically on the backend but I'm not sure (sorry been a while since I've done Java).  But yeah in angular this definitely has to be sent as a string unforunately.

Comment: you can use `include.contentEquals("true")` to avoid parsing boolean value

Comment: @sanjeevRm Can you please let me know where? If you are ok to post the revised code, it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Spring automatically takes care of converting to intended data type so fixed the problem by

```
@GetMapping(value="/employee")
public EmployeeList list(@RequestParam String dept,@RequestParam boolean include) {
   
   .............
}
```